# linear convolution using delta functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convolution, signal-processing

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrFza.png)

What is the linear convolution between x(n) and v(2n)

[multiple choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98OP0.png)

So far my professor was doing the convolution only with the tabular method and I don't know how to do this using delta functions

Comment: Welcome to MSE Bob. Please, instead of adding links to picture or uploading them, type your question  as suggested in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider adding some details showing your efforts or explaining your doubts.

Comment: My professor didn't explain anything about the delta functions so I cannot start to solve them if I could transform the plot into delta functions I would try to solve it, this is my first obstacle

Comment: @BobJhonson First step towards asking for more help is to politely respond to what was suggested. To answer your question, if you know or google up the definition fo delta function, can you draw a graph for $\delta(n-1)?$

Answer (score 0):

We want the convolution of $\delta(x+1)+2\delta(x)+\delta(x-1)$ with $\delta(x+2)+\delta(x-2)$. Since these respectively integrate to $4,\,2$, the problem is equivalent to determining the distribution of $X+Y$ in terms of Dirac spikes, with independent $X,\,Y$ where$$P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\tfrac14,\,P(X=0)=P(Y=2)=P(Y=-2)=\tfrac12,$$then multiplying all weights by $8$. So now you don't even need calculus. You're welcome to determine the full result from first principles, but for a multiple choice question we have a shortcut. All weights must be $\ge0$ (this is an advantage of recasting the problem into probabilities), which eliminates B, C and D, and $X+Y=-3$ is achievable, which eliminates E, so A is right.